# Problem with outputting map values in scala

Tags: scala

I have the following code snippet:

```
val map = new LinkedHashMap[String,String]
map.put("City","Dallas")
println(map.get("City"))
```

This outputs `Some(Dallas)` instead of just `Dallas`. Whats the problem with my code ?

Thank You

Answer (score 18):

Use the `apply` method, it returns directly the `String` and throws a `NoSuchElementException` if the key is not found:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap

scala> val map = new LinkedHashMap[String,String]
map: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String] = Map()

scala> map.put("City","Dallas")
res2: Option[String] = None

scala> map("City")
res3: String = Dallas
```

Comment: `apply` is a magic method that gets called if you 'call' an object. `map("City")` is equivalent to `map.apply("City")`.

Answer (score 13):

It's not really a problem.

While Java's Map version uses `null` to indicate that a key don't have an associated value, Scala's `Map[A,B].get` returns a `Options[B]`, which can be `Some[B]` or `None`, and None plays a similar role to java's `null`.

REPL session showing why this is useful:

```
scala> map.get("State")
res6: Option[String] = None

scala> map.get("State").getOrElse("Texas")
res7: String = Texas
```

Or the not recommended but simple `get`:

```
scala> map.get("City").get
res8: String = Dallas

scala> map.get("State").get
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:262)
```

Check the [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/Option.html) documentation for more goodies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how to make it output just the value instead of Some(value) ?

Comment: @Tom I have just add one example of how to use it.

Comment: @Tom: You could just use `map("City")`.

Comment: Related post on better alternative to `map.get().get` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969225/getting-map-keys-value-cleanly

Answer (score 2):

There are two more ways you can handle `Option` results.

You can pattern match them:

```
scala> map.get("City") match {
 |   case Some(value) => println(value)
 |   case _ => println("found nothing")
 | }
Dallas
```

Or there is another neat approach that appears somewhere in *Programming in Scala*. Use `foreach` to process the result. If a result is of type `Some`, then it will be used. Otherwise (if it's `None`), nothing happens:

```
scala> map.get("City").foreach(println)
Dallas

scala> map.get("Town").foreach(println)
```