# Getting Map Key's Value Cleanly

Tags: scala

How can I idiomatically get a `Map` key's value if I know that it exists?

```
scala> val m = Map(1 -> "hi", 2 -> "world")
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> hi, 2 -> world)

scala> if (m.contains(1)) println(m.get(1) )
Some(hi)
```

Is there a more idiomatic alternative over `m.get(1).get.get`?

```
scala> if (m.contains(1)) println(m.get(1).get )
hi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scala `Map` has `apply` method:

```
scala> m.apply(1)
res1: String = hi
```

or with syntax sugar:

```
scala> m(1)
res0: String = hi
```

But more idiomatic ways is to iterate over `Option`:

```
scala> m.get(1) foreach println
hi
```

Comment: I wouldn't call the `get` approach more idiomatic. Only safer when the presence of the key is unknown. If you have a code path that guarantees the presence of the key, there's no need for the `get` circumlocution and it's just more code (including a function literal that has to be generated by the compiler, loaded by the class loader and instantiated at run time).

Comment: If we prefer code size and performance over safety, then we must throw away Option at all :) You're right, may be 'idiomatic' is the wrong word here.

Comment: But, @SergeyPassichenko, isn't this part the difference "**Only safer when the presence of the key is unknown**"? In my case, I'm using an `if (map.contains(key)) map(key)`. Since `map` is immutable, `map(key)` is a code path where `map(key)` will **always** return a value.

Comment: First of all, it's subjective and depends on your style. Personally, I don't think, that `if (map.contains(key)) map(key)` is safe. Because of the same reasons that `if (x != null) x.something` isn't safe. But if you know, that key should always be in map (limited or predefined number of keys etc.), then you can safely use `apply`. Also, you may find useful `getOrElse`.